# Customize node shape and "fork" in forest tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest

I am struggling to make a phylogenic tree.

Below is a minimal example :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes,snakes}



\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
   % insert coordinates in empty node
innov/.style={
      edge label={node[auto, sloped,pos=.75,anchor=east]{#1}}
    },
delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate}{}},
where n children=0{tier=word}{},              % align nodes at bottom of tree
    for tree={
      forked edge,        % for forked edge
            s sep = 2mm,    % sibling distance
            l sep = 6mm,    % level distance
         fork sep = 3mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
              }
              [ to upper in the tree, text centered [, innov =innovation
                [species 1][species 2]]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

What I would like to obtain is displayed in the image below.
By order of decreasing importance :

1. Customization should work independently of tree level
2. Solid circle at the fork (this represents the last common ancestor, so it is very important from a semantic point of view)
3. Horizontal line to show the apparition of the biological innovation
4. It would be better if the biological innovation could be represented by a custom edge rather than a node to simplify the node hierarchy and make it more similar to biological significance.
5. Have more space between the last letter of innovation and the line (it is not very important, I can already increase this space by ~ ~.

Having only 1 and 2 would already make my day.

[image: goal tree]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this does most of what you want. You can make a node style `dot` and set `fork sep=-1pt` (which is the radius of the dot). The line can be a rectangular node with `inner ysep=0pt` and a label to its right.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
   % insert coordinates in empty node
innov/.style={
      edge label={node[draw, minimum height=0pt, inner ysep=0, pos=.75, label={left:#1}]{}}
    },
dot/.style={fill, circle, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum size=2pt},
delay={where content={}{dot}{}},
where n children=0{tier=word}{},              % align nodes at bottom of tree
    for tree={
      forked edge,        % for forked edge
            s sep = 2mm,    % sibling distance
            l sep = 6mm,    % level distance
         fork sep = -1pt,    % subtract half of minimum size
              }
              [ to upper in the tree, text centered [, innov =innovation
                [species 1][species 2]]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is really nice.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

- "innovation" is added with two labels
- dot is draw separately

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\tikzset{
    dot/.style={circle, fill, inner sep=1.2pt, node contents={}},
        }



\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
            align = center,
      forked edge,          % for forked edge
            s sep = 2mm,    % sibling distance
            l sep = 6mm,    % level distance
         fork sep = 4mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
%
where n children=0{tier=word}{},              % align nodes at bottom of tree
delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate}{}},
              }
[ to upper in the tree
    [, label=center: -- , label=left:innovation\vphantom{p}, name=a
        [species 1]
        [species 2]
    ]
]
\path (a) ++ (0,-4mm) node[dot];    % vertical distance is equal to 4mm
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
for shorter `forest` code is handy to define style of node "innovation", which insert its both labels. Let be named `inv`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\tikzset{
    dot/.style={circle, fill, inner sep=1.2pt, node contents={}},
        }

\begin{document}
\newcommand\fd{3mm}  % <--- new, for common determining of fork distance
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
        align = center,
  forked edge,          % for forked edge
        s sep = 2mm,    % sibling distance
        l sep = 6mm,    % level distance
     fork sep = \fd,    % distance from parent to branching point
   inv/.style = {label=center:--,label={[yshift=0.4ex]left: #1~~}},  % <-- new
%
where n children=0{tier=word}{},              % align nodes at bottom of tree
delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate}{}},
              }
[ to upper in the tree
    [, inv=innovation, name=a
        [species 1]
        [species 2]
    ]
]
\path (a) ++ (0,-\fd) node[dot];    % vertical distance is equal to fork sep
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code makes me discover possibilities in Forest I was not aware of.